# Creating ensemble and aggregates

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I have downloaded [climate forecast data in NetCDF 3.6 format](https://nedlasting.nve.no/klimadata/kss) for a series of models and time resolution of one day. The data is one file per model. Eventually, I would like to have an ensemble file with aggregated data over the time axis, e.g. monthly or quarterly. Maybe it gets clearer when I just list some names of the files I have:

- rcp85_CNRM_CCLM_RR_daily_mm_2100.nc
- rcp85_CNRM_RCA_RR_daily_mm_2100.nc
- rcp85_EC-EARTH_CCLM_RR_daily_mm_2100.nc

I expect all the files to have the same extent and resolution; gdalinfo excerpts of arbitrary two files https://pastebin.com/UtxXDDGp support my assumption.

Being a complete noob, I assume that the ensemble would just be the arithmetic average, but I do not know how to average the "payload" axis of rasters over different layers nor over its timeseries/bands.

The [manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/index.html) is not helping me and [Ecosia](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=qgis%20ensemble) and [OS-GEOS](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=3681316&query=ensemble) search was not helpful either.

Is this possible with QGIS and how would I do it?

About of my QGIS installation gives:

```
QGIS version                3.14.0-Pi           QGIS code branch           Release 3.14
Compiled against Qt         5.15.0              Running against Qt         5.15.0
Compiled against GDAL/OGR   3.1.2               Running against GDAL/OGR   3.1.2
Compiled against GEOS       3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3   Running against GEOS       3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Compiled against SQLite     3.32.3              Running against SQLite     3.33.0
PostgreSQL Client Version   12.3                SpatiaLite Version         4.3.0a
QWT Version                 6.1.5               QScintilla2 Version        2.11.3
Compiled against PROJ       7.0.1               Running against PROJ       Rel. 7.0.1, May 1st, 2020
OS Version                  openSUSE Tumbleweed This copy of QGIS writes debugging output.
Active python plugins       processing; 
                            MetaSearch; 
                            db_manager
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Do these rasters have all the same extent and resolution?

Comment: The raster calculator should do the trick.

Comment: I do not know what a raster calculator is.

Comment: Could you give more details on the raster calculator?